# MethodChannel System Services not available to Activities before onCreate() [Kotlin]

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I tried create my custom plugin for Flutter on Kotlin. I accessed the methodChannel and was able to do it, but when I want to use the bluetooth service in the methodChannel i am faicng this error. I did on Kotlin and my code ran correctly. The difference is My kotlin app's class is of type AppCompatActivity() and has onCreate() function. My problem was not solved when I added the onCreate function to my scanner.kt file. I get this error.

```
> E/MethodChannel#beacon_scanner: Failed to handle method call
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>         at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:6868)
>         at com.example.beacon_scanner.BeaconScannerPlugin$onMethodCall$bluetoothAdapter$2.invoke(BeaconScannerPlugin.kt:52)
>         at com.example.beacon_scanner.BeaconScannerPlugin$onMethodCall$bluetoothAdapter$2.invoke(BeaconScannerPlugin.kt:49)
>         at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
>         at com.example.beacon_scanner.BeaconScannerPlugin.onMethodCall$lambda-0(BeaconScannerPlugin.kt:49)
>         at com.example.beacon_scanner.BeaconScannerPlugin.onMethodCall(BeaconScannerPlugin.kt:57)
>         at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
>         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
>         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
>         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown
> Source:12)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
> E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled
> Exception: PlatformException(error, System services not available to
> Activities before onCreate(), null, java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>         at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:6868)
>         at com.example.beacon_scanner.BeaconScannerPlugin$onMethodCall$bluetoothAdapter$2.invoke(BeaconScannerPlugin.kt:52)
>         at com.example.beacon_scanner.BeaconScannerPlugin$onMethodCall$bluetoothAdapter$2.invoke(BeaconScannerPlugin.kt:49)
>         at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
>         at com.example.beacon_scanner.BeaconScannerPlugin.onMethodCall$lambda-0(BeaconScannerPlugin.kt:49)
>         at com.example.beacon_scanner.BeaconScannerPlugin.onMethodCall(BeaconScannerPlugin.kt:57)
>         at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
>         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
>         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
>         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown
> Source:12)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>     )
>     #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
>     #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
>     <asynchronous suspension>
>     #2      BeaconScanner.bluetoothIsActive (package:beacon_scanner/beacon_scanner.dart:14:12)
>     <asynchronous suspension>
>     #3      _MyAppState.getBtStatus (package:beacon_scanner_example/main.dart:50:17)
>     <asynchronous suspension>
```

And that's my code:

**scanner.dart**

```
class BeaconScanner {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('beacon_scanner');

  static Future<String?> get platformVersion async {
    final String? version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
    return version;
  }
  static Future get bluetoothIsActive async {
    return await _channel.invokeMethod('bluetoothIsActive');
  }
  static Future get sayHello async {
    final btStatus = await _channel.invokeMethod('sayHello');
    return btStatus.toString();
  }
}
```

**scanner.kt**

```
  class BeaconScannerPlugin: FlutterActivity(), FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel
  private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter by lazy{
    (getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager).adapter
  }

  companion object {
    private const val BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 9999
  }

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "beacon_scanner")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)

  }

  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
      result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
    }
    else if (call.method=="bluetoothIsActive") {

      if(bluetoothAdapter != null){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
          ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
          initializeBluetoothOrRequestPermission()
        }
        if(bluetoothAdapter.enable()){
          result.success("bt status is ${bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled}")
          Log.v("Scanner","ENABLED")
        }
        else {
          initializeBluetoothOrRequestPermission()
        }
      }
    }else if (call.method=="sayHello") {
          result.success("bt status is HELLO  YES")
    }
    else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  private fun initializeBluetoothOrRequestPermission() {
    val requiredPermissions = listOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
    val missingPermissions = requiredPermissions.filter { permission ->
      ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
    if (missingPermissions.isEmpty()) {
    } else {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, missingPermissions.toTypedArray(), BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BeaconScannerPlugin` is an Activity and as the error stacktrace says, it needs to be in the created state before you can use it in `getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)`.

You should change your `BeaconScannerPlugin` implementation to not depend on `FlutterActivity` and instead use `ActivityAware` interface.

`ActivityAware` will give you an instace of activity that you can use to get the bluetooth service for your plugin.

You can read more on the [official flutter webiste](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration#uiactivity-plugin)